# Public to Local IP Communication

Tags: java, spring, web, networking, desktop

I have created project which has two components as Desktop client and web.

web server is communicating to the my another program which i run as client on other systems.

After connecting those clients communication is happening in network as all IP's within network are reachable.

However, when i deployed web app on public IP now i am not able to connect the clients as the local IP's of those clients are not reachable by server.

How can i achieve this communication between local IP to public and vice versa?

Comment: Establish a soclet connection from the local client to the public server and use it from both sides as it is duplex.

Comment: Look up NAT hole punching for the standard solution to this problem. Otherwise you can just do the naive solution and use your server to forward all calls between the clients.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. 
Anyways, if you want the service to be reachable publically then you´ll probalby want to forward the Port to the machine running the service.
Also, make sure the Firewall allows connections to this port.

Since you´re talking about Web-Apps it´s probably HTTP, Port 80 TCP, or HTTPS, the encrypted version of HTTP running on port 443 TCP.

To explain it, your ISP gives you one public IP address.
Since you probably have multiple devices using internet, they all appear in the internet as the one IP address your provider gave you.
Whenever you send something out your router will remember where you tried to connect and if a response comes in your router knows which device to send the response to.

Now, since you want someone to connect to you, there was no request so your router does not know where to put the packet and simply blocks it.
In most routers you can configure something usually called NAT or Port Forwarding. You simply specify that communication on Port 80 or 443 should be routed to the internal IP. It has one of the following formats:
192.168.0.1 - 192.168.255.254 
172.16.XXX.XXX - 172.31.255.254
10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.254